# Помогите разобраться с существующим кодом

Tags: c++

Всем привет, не могу понять **решение задачи**, вот само условие(решение в конце):
Имеется база регионов, представленная вектором структур Region:

```
 struct Region {
  string std_name;
  string parent_std_name;
  map<Lang, string> names;
  int64_t population;
};
```

Здесь Lang — идентификатор языка:

```
  enum class Lang {
     DE, FR, IT
  };
```

Напишите функцию FindMaxRepetitionCount, принимающую базу регионов и определяющую, какое максимальное количество повторов она содержит. Две записи (объекты типа Region) считаются различными, если они отличаются хотя бы одним полем.

> int FindMaxRepetitionCount(const vector& regions);

---

Итак, вот само решение:

```
#include <map>

#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool operator<(const Region& lhs, const Region& rhs) {
  return tie(lhs.std_name, lhs.parent_std_name, lhs.names, lhs.population) <
      tie(rhs.std_name, rhs.parent_std_name, rhs.names, rhs.population);
}

int FindMaxRepetitionCount(const vector<Region>& regions) {
  int result = 0;
  map<Region, int> repetion_count;
  for (const Region& region : regions) {
    result = max(result, ++repetion_count[region]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Могли бы вы немного прояснить мне ситуацию:

1. Перегруженный оператор сравнения нужен для функции max? Если да, тогда как он сравнивает с rezult, он же int?
2. Цикл for можно заменить на for( auto region : regions )? Какие вообще значения принимает region? Если представить цикл

> for(int i = 0; i < regions.size(); i++)

, то region и regions[i] будут иметь схожий смысл?
 3. Самое топ что вообще не понимаю - зачем в max инкремент?

А это пример входных данных :

```
int main() {
  cout << FindMaxRepetitionCount({
      {
          "Moscow",
          "Russia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Russia",
          "Eurasia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Russland"}, {Lang::FR, "Russie"}, {Lang::IT, "Russia"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Moscow",
          "Russia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Moscow",
          "Russia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Russia",
          "Eurasia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Russland"}, {Lang::FR, "Russie"}, {Lang::IT, "Russia"}},
          89
      },
  }) << endl;

  cout << FindMaxRepetitionCount({
      {
          "Moscow",
          "Russia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Russia",
          "Eurasia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Russland"}, {Lang::FR, "Russie"}, {Lang::IT, "Russia"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Moscow",
          "Russia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou deux"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Moscow",
          "Toulouse",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          89
      }, {
          "Moscow",
          "Russia",
          {{Lang::DE, "Moskau"}, {Lang::FR, "Moscou"}, {Lang::IT, "Mosca"}},
          31
      },
  }) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

***3 1*** это вывод

Comment: добавлю, что всё это было уже в C++11

Answer (score 1):

> Перегруженный оператор сравнения нужен для функции max? Если да, тогда как он сравнивает с rezult, он же int?

Ну так и `++repetion_count[region]` - тоже `int`. Ваш `max` работает с аргументами типа `int` - ему никакой перегруженный оператор сравнения не нужен.

Перегруженный оператор сравнения нужен для `map<Region, int>`.

> Цикл for можно заменить на for( auto region : regions )?

Можно, но нет смысла итерировать "по значению". Разумнее тогда уж `for(const auto &region : regions )`. Или просто `for(auto &region : regions )`, ибо константность получится автоматически.

> Если представить цикл `for(int i = 0; i < regions.size(); i++)`, то `region` и `regions[i]` будут иметь схожий смысл?

Да.

> зачем в max инкремент?

Этот инкремент - и есть подсчет количества повторов, ради которого все и писалось.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.
Так получается, что оператор сравнения вовсе не нужен?
++repetion_count[region]
подставляя в repetion_count region мы получаем второй вид данных, лежащий в map - int, который в свою очередь и увеличивается инкрементом ?

Comment: @MarkSD: "Вовсе не нужен"? Еще раз: перегруженный оператор сравнения обязательно **нужен** для `map<Region, int>`. Без него не получится сделать `map<Region, int>`.

Comment: Прошу прощения за твердолобость.  Какую роль играет оператор сравнения в map<Region, int>?

Comment: @MarkSD: `std::map` - упорядоченный контейнер. Его функциональность критически опирается на возможность сравнивать ключи между собой, причем не просто на "равен - не равен", а на *относительный порядок* (т.е. "больше" или "меньше"). Для того, чтобы использовать некий тип в качестве *ключевого* в `std::map` (в вашем случае - это `Region`), этот тип должен поддерживать сравнение на "меньше". Способ такого сравнения можно "передать" в `std::map` разными способами. Простейший способ - просто перегрузить оператор `<` для ключевого типа.